# Can't test Styled Component in Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, styled-components

When trying to run a simple Snapshot test, I get the following:

```
TypeError: _styledComponents2.default.View is not a function

      2 | import styled from "styled-components";
      3 |
    > 4 | const ButtonContainer = styled.View`
      5 |   flex-direction: row;
      6 |   align-items: center;
      7 |   justify-content: center;
```

I've tried:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "styled-components":
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.native.cjs.js"
    }
```

And also adding https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components

But I have had no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "moduleNameMapper" object is inside "jest" block.